# High Speed Light Detection in Daylight

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, photodiode, camera

I'm trying to create a system to detect when a set of lights trigger in drag racing to the thousandth of a second. However, all my attempts at finding cameras for a raspberry pi or arduino aren't quite fast enough. Is there a camera out there capable of this, or another way to do this perhaps using some other component?

The process of detection is fairly simple. There are two sets of lights and I want to detect when the first triggers, and when the second triggers (while the first is still on.)

Comment: Lateral approach: patch into the signal which controls the light.

Comment: @Nick Alexeev; I suspect he wants to control the dragster engine by electronics when the light goes green.   If so, I don't think the organisers will grant him access to the controls. Also I suspect the 1/1000 sec. accuracy will be overshadowed by the uncertainty in the engine, wheel grips etc.

Comment: Its more for comparative purposes. The person that wants this *says* he wants to see his actual reaction time in the cockpit as he's racing.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [color sensor](http://ams.com/eng/content/download/319904/1118122/142695) looking directly at the lamp only without indirect light (e.g. through a long black tube).

Answer (score 0):

Almost all sensors start with photodiodes, which are far faster than 1msec.
The reason cameras are slower is that they are huge arrays of photodiodes, accumulating charge in a small capacitor for each, then  reading out each diode+cap in the row sequentially.  Rastered readout takes time when the numbers of elements are big.  Maybe you like cameras because they measure light over a large spread of locations, then you pick one in software.  I'm not sure you can make that work. 
Maybe an unusual camera with a small number of pixels could work, I dunno.
  Any chance you could use a single photo-diode (or photo-transistor) & lens pointed right at your starting light?  If the light had any AC humm in the current driving it, you could detect that too in your signal, to indicate while you aimed and waited, that your lens was properly aimed at the light.   If not, get a photodiode in a clear plastic body & paste it in the center of a small translucent screen.  I used a white soda-bottle cap once, worked ok at night for pointing at illuminated windows in the dark.

Comment: The main parameter in photodiodes is their sensitive area. It can be <1mm2, up to 1.0cm2.  1-2mm diam. might be best for your app.    Lens optic geometry:  the image of the light on the photodiode should approximately match the photodiode active area.  I suspect you wont need a really big lens. 1cm, 1inch?

Comment: It's been a while since I took a class on lenses, but I think the biggest issue I had with using a photodiode was that it would need to be aimed. From what I'm told, the lamps are quite a distance away in addition to being positioned very close to one another, so aiming at a specific light reliably would be a challenge.

Comment: I conceed that can be a show-stopper.  Thanks for mentioning it.